# How do I get to this chest behind the revolving statues?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

There is a treasure vault that has a chest behind the revolving statues. Standing on the platform rotates and you end up on the other platform, rather than the other side of the wall.

[image: chest behind the revolving statues]

How do I get to the other side?

Tried a number of things, like using lumos (light) on while on the platform and nothing I've tried worked.

This one is across the lake from Hogwarts, south of Aranshire.

[image: map]

Comment: Where did you find this statues? Maybe I can go there and try.

Comment: I added the location to it. You'll need accio (pull) and incendio (fire) to be able to enter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've gone there and solved it!

You'll need Glacius magic (the one that freezes enemies and some thing).

You have to use that magic to the brazier, and the fire will be extinguished, so it makes the statue to rotate, and voila you'll be able to take the chests.

[Took a video of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOWsqgHgq6w), if you want to see how it works.

Comment: Great! Dang, I had it too at the time, but never tried. Thanks!